# Обфускация библиотеки

Tags: android, android-library, обфускация, jitpack.io

Нужно в библиотеке оставить расположение пакетов и название методов в исходном виде.
Нужно максимально обфуцировать содержимое методов.

Помогите составить правило для proguard..

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить структуру можно так

```
-keep class ru.domain.package.** { *; }

 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```